# Log files back up - problem

Tags: java, linux, unix, shell, log4j

Hi i am having small application using log4j,

it run 24*7, i want to back up log file since its keep growing bigger.

anyone suggest me best way to backup and continue logging without data loss.

(backup log file - log continues from that backup)

Note: using linux OS

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should just use a `RollingFileAppender` and create a new log file based on date or size. Then backup the previous log files.

Try: [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) or some subclass of [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html) (here's [an example](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/08/howto-using-apaches-log4j-rollingfileappender-an-example.html)).

Just get those appenders into your class path and setup the corresponding configuration in your log4j.properties or log4j.xml.

Comment: Probably not. StackOverflow does not write your code or think for you. We're not too hot on people who ask questions and don't even vote on the correct answers; please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq